# How to assign a value to IFormattableString? ( $"hi {name}" in c# 6.0 new IFormattablestring feature)

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

How do I manage to assign a value to IFormattableString ?

Is it not possible to use as follows

```
string name = "Booley";
string template = "Hi mr. {name}, hope you enjoy the chicken!";

Console.WriteLine(template,name);
```

Output

```
Hi mr. Booley, hope you enjoy the chicken!
```

I know how to achieve this, but I'm curious why you cannot use the new  C# 6.0 feature to make this.  Variable names only available at compile time ?

Comment: I do not understand the question. You talk about `IFormattableString`, but then you don't use it in your code. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You miss $ before the string. It should be `string template = $"Hi mr. {name}, hope you enjoy the chicken!";`

Comment: Thats the point, I don't want to use the $, I want to load the string from a file.

Comment: @hreinn1000 This comment doesn't make sense. Either you want string interpolation (strings starting with `$`) or not. String interpolation is a *language* feature, implemented by the compiler, not a new syntax for format strings. Where would the *runtime* find the variable names specified in a string loaded from a file? IL doesn't store variable names.